# How to create an array of strings in a linked list node

Tags: java, linked-list

I've been playing around with linked lists and I want to know if it's possible to have an array of strings in a linked list node. I've been trying to get it to work the same way as the string "name", so that I can insert more strings into the array as needed

```
class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node n = new Node("Ace");
    }
}

class Node {
    private Node next;
    private String name;
    private String[] data;

    public Node(String s1) {
        s1 = name;
        next = null;
    }

    public String[] getArray() {
        return array;
    }

    public void setData(String s1, int point) {
        name = s1;
        array
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node nextVal) {
        next = nextVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? What did you expect to see/happen and what did you see/happened instead?

Comment: You may have a design problem here.  Do you intend each `Node` to hold one and only one name?  Or, can a given `Node` correspond to more than one name?

Comment: I'm trying to add array entries into the node the same way I do with the name entry and Node n= new Node("");
Ideally I'm looking for a solution that lets me enter more strings into the array once the node has been initialized
I only need one name for each node as well

Comment: @Jabba, "Ideally I'm looking for a solution that lets me enter more strings into the array once the node has been initialized I only need one name for each node as well". Does this mean the you want to dynamically add strings to the array contained within the node?

Comment: @Brady Sheehan, Yeah. I'm guessing that's possible?

Comment: You can't dynamically grow an array. Use a List for that (Vector, ArrayList, etc).

Answer (score 1):

You can have a String array in your linked list, but you cannot extend an array once it is allocated.

If you want to have something extensible, you should use an `ArrayList`.